# Cross platform C++ filesystem watcher

Tags: c++, filesystems, cross-platform, filesystemwatcher

I'm looking for a cross platform file system watcher, similar to the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class in .NET. As it's for a daemon/service, I'm not keen on Qt's [QFileSystemWatcher](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qfilesystemwatcher.html). I'd really like to avoid it as I don't want to have a dependency on Qt as my program is going to be a daemon.

I've also seen a [proposal](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2010/04/165719.php) for such a class to be included in Boost, but as far as I know such a class has not yet been included.

Is there a cross platform C++ file system watcher?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qt is divided into [modules](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/modules.html), so using this feature doesn't mean you have to use the GUI library.

QFileSystemWatcher is in [QtCore](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtcore.html), which has no GUI functionality.

Comment: I was just about to say that. He still could argue that QtCore is too big. But yes, it's still a fair deal considering the amount of work that requires supporting inotify, kqueue, WaitForMultipleObjects in the same implementation.

Comment: [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) also has [a wxFileSystemWatcher](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_file_system_watcher.html) implementation, but it has some limitations.

Comment: @dschulz, and considering that he's comparing to the .NET System.dll (and everything System.dll directly or indirectly depends on for a given platform), which isn't known for being svelte.

Comment: .NET isn't svelte, but that has no bearing on question. QtCore is fairly heavy weight and it contains tons of stuff I'm not interested in.

Comment: This is probably the closest we get to a cross platform file system watcher.

Answer (score 2):

I have not used this (I came to this question looking for alternatives), but http://code.google.com/p/simplefilewatcher seems to be a good option. It is not currently maintained, but the relevant APIs are probably fairly stable. I'll try to remember to update this answer if I use this library.

Comment: simple file watcher is limited on mac osx due to the use of kqueue. QFileWatcher is what you want to use.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative there is also "Entropia File System Watcher"

https://bitbucket.org/SpartanJ/efsw which is a fork of the simple-file-watcher.

> efsw currently supports the following platforms:
>
> Linux via inotify
>
> Windows via I/O Completion Ports
>
> Mac OS X via FSEvents or kqueue
>
> FreeBSD/BSD via kqueue
>
> OS-independent generic watcher (polling the disk for directory
>   snapshots and comparing them periodically)
>
> If any of the backend fails to start by any reason, it will fallback
>   to the OS-independent implementation.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness sake, it is also worth mentioning Poco's [DirectoryWatcher](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.DirectoryWatcher.html).