# How to wait for a file to exist (and be released)?

Tags: c++, boost, std, file-access

Is there a library with a function that blocks the caller until a certain file exists and/or is deletable? (Very preferably in the standard C++ libraries or boost.)

## Background

I'm a C++ newcomer writing a single-threaded application that needs to

1. Perform some heavy calculations on start up.
2. Wait for a certain input file to exist (and be deletable).
3. If the file contains a certain instruction, delete it and exit.
4. (Else) process it, delete it, and produce an output file.
5. Repeat from step 2.

The reason for having steps 2,3 and 5 (instead of just step 1&4 and invoking the application on demand) is that step 1 involves some heavy processing.

I don't want to spend a lot of processor time busy-waiting during step 2, but I also don't want to introduce unnecessary latency by polling for the file's existence infrequently.

What is the right approach here? (Preferably cross-platform: Windows, Linux, OSX.)

Comment: Just for the sake of it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10164341/cross-platform-c-filesystem-watcher - not boost or standard library (which has nothing on file systems yet), but might be useful.

Comment: Re *Wait for a certain input file to exist (and be deletable).* The first part is easy. Try to open the file. Wait a bit and try again if you get an error. The parenthetical part is anything but easy. What does that even mean, particularly in a cross-platform sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an Asio service that abstracts over

- Win32 filemonitoring API
- `inotify` on Linux (and friends?)

floating around on the web. It has not been accepted into Boost yet, although some discussion is going on to include it with Boost Asio (the library for *asynchronous IO*)

Found this, which might help you find it:

- mailing list thread: http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/filesystem-file-monitoring-td2652549.html
- https://github.com/kvikas/file-monitor-service/blob/master/inotify/file_monitor_service.hpp

Answer (score 1):

It certainly is operating system (and file system) specific. On Linux specifically you could [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) facilities (with native Linux *local* file systems like Ext4 or BTRFS).

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there is a library that abstracts over the OS- and FS-specifics for me. I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Why would you imagine that every OS feature could be wrapped in an OS & FS neutral way?

Comment: I was just hoping that *this* one can, for the three given platforms (assuming "OS & FS neutral" means OS & FS invariant API -- correct me if I misunderstood.)